# Importing component from bundle.js file , Trying to used in html template

Tags: reactjs

I have created a bundle of components Eg:** Project A ** using webpack. your text  ** Basically The components inside Project A bundling of the this component is like this:** import React from "react";  `const ActionBox = (props) => { console.log(props); const { heading, description, variant, color, children, ...rest } = props;  return ( <> <div className="container"> <div className={text-center rounded py-5 px-3 ${variant}}> {heading} {description} </div> </div> </> ); };  export default ActionBox; ` ** result **:we get ** bundle.js **  ** Project B ** Now That bundle i m using in HTML PAGE by giving reFrenece in html page like this after that i have added react cdn also    < script type = "text/babel" src = "./build/bundle.js" ></ >     <script       crossorigin       src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"     ></script>     <script       crossorigin       src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"     ></script>     <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>  **in Project B in that html file we are passing component data using data attribute like below code   **  < !--================================= Action Box-- > <section       id="react-container"       class="space-pb dark-background"       data-component="call-to-action"       data-heading=" Tell us about your idea, and we’ll make it happen."       data-description="Have a brand problem that needs to be solved? We’d love to hear about it!"       data-variant="bg-dark"       data-color="text-white"     ></section> <!--================================= z Action Box-- >  ** Now this data attribute data / info  im trying to pass into ActionBox Component with help  OF jquery and React.render see below code **  import React from "react"; import ReactDOM from "react-dom"  import { ActionBox } from './build/bundle';  (function ($) { "use strict";  $("[data-component='call-to-action']").each(function () {  `** data is receving in this variable below ** here var color = $(this).data("color"); var description = $(this).data("description"); var heading = $(this).data("heading"); var variant = $(this).data("variant");  var propsData = {   heading: { heading },   description: { description },   variant: { variant },   color: { color }, };  ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("react-container")).render(   <ActionBox     heading={heading}     description={description}     variant={variant}     color={color}   /> ); ReactDOM.render(``your text``   React.createElement(ActionBox, propsData),   document.getElementById("react-container") );  }); your text console.log("This is react component"); })(jQuery); your text `  But data is passed in variable but not passing in ActionBox component.  I am getting this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AFkN.png)  `

Comment: Can you include your code properly? It is tough to get what exactly you're looking for from your question.